# Sending email VB 2012

Tags: email, smtp, send

I have to send an email from my VB 2012 application and i have tryed different function that i found on the net.
I used System.Net.Mail library usign MailAddress, SmtpClient ecc.
The application doesn't give me any exception but no email are sent.
The same function with a VB 2010 application work perfectly also executing that in the 2012 IDE. I don't understand why =(
Look my function

```
Private Sub InviaMailProva2(ByVal SmtpServer As String, ByVal usermail As String, ByVal sender As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal receiver As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal body As String)
    Dim email As New MailMessage
    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
    email.From = New MailAddress(usermail)
    email.Subject = subject
    email.To.Add(receiver)
    smtp.Port = 25     'i use an aruba email, it work with other application'
    smtp.Host = SmtpServer
    smtp.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(user, password)
    smtp.Send(email)
End Sub
```

Comment: So you wanna send some email?  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html  Your email is sent, it's just you are probably being treated as an email spammer and your email is ignored.

Comment: @Eric Leschinski Well that puts it in a different light doesn't it O-o

Comment: @EricLeschinski but why the other application with the same code work perfectly?

Comment: I used the same code into an other VB application but with VB 2010, and it work.